# Why does my 'ubuntu' user not need a password when using sudo

Tags: sudo, password

In the default ubuntu amazon image, it's not required to use a password to use sudo.

To allow someone to do this with sudo, generally I need to add a line to `sudoers` such as:

```
%sudo ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

However, the default configuration file doesn't mention `NOPASSWD` anywhere. How is this configured?

Comment: It is built into the amazon image. Google cloud does the same.

Comment: @Rinzwind I understand, but I want to understand *how*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would search in /etc/sudoers.d folder.

```
cd  /etc/sudoers.d
grep NOPASSWD *
```

Comment: It will survive systemupdates, it is discussed in https://askubuntu.com/questions/930768/adding-local-content-in-etc-sudoers-d-instead-of-directly-modifying-sodoers-fi

Comment: I looked but didn't get anything, just realized it was because the directory is 700 and I assumed it just didn't exists. Thank you!