# How to allow non sudoers users to run a script that does root operations

Tags: permissions, scripts, sudo

Supouse I have a directory `/opt/expe` and I want any user to create .txt files on it. I want any user to type something like this:

```
$ whoami
user1
$ export $file_name=my_txt_file
$ /opt/expe/create_file.sh
$ ls -cal /opt/expe
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 2 root  root 4096 Jul 29 19:27 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root  root 4096 Jul 29 19:14 ..
-rwsr-sr-t 1 root  root   65 Jul 29 19:29 create_file.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 user1 root    0 Jul 29 19:27 my_txt_file.txt
```

I try this with a sudoer

```
$ whoami
user_sudoer
$ cat /opt/expe/create_file.sh
touch /opt/expe/$file_name.txt
chown $USER /opt/expe/$file_name.txt
$ chmod a+x /opt/expe/create_file.sh
$ chmod a+t /opt/expe/create_file.sh
$ chmod a+s /opt/expe/create_file.sh
$ chmod a+X /opt/expe/create_file.sh
```

Then with non-root user I obtained:

```
$ whoami
user1
$ export $file_name=my_txt_file
$ /opt/expe/create_file.sh
touch: cannot touch '/opt/expe/prueba_txt.txt': Permission denied
```

Can I do something like this. I want something like postgres `SECURITY DEFINER` concept.

Comment: Are all the users in the same `group`? `chmod 775 /opt/expe` or `chmod 777 /opt/expe`. Why should I learn about "postgres SECURITY DEFINER concept"? What parts of it do you need?

Comment: Can you please post output of ls -ld /opt/expe ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with Postgres enough, but I see at least 4 options:

1. Change permissions of /opt/expe with chmod to allow all users create files within this directory.
2. Create a separate group for the users which need to write there and change /opt/expe group permission with chmod to allow this group write there.
3. Create a separate group and add sudoers rule to let them execute this script as described for example here: [How can user mount an encrypted file container in VeraCrypt?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/930724/how-can-user-mount-an-encrypted-file-container-in-veracrypt)
4. Use label security for fine-grained access control. Here is brief description of security labels and some further links: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/53028/what-are-ext4-security-labels

Please bear in mind that the permission to create/remove files is a property of the directory and not the file itself.

Comment: Options 1 & 2 are not what I ask. Option 4 is interesting but I don't found an answer in it. Option 3 looks like I need, I try something but it doesn't works. Here Is my refined question: https://askubuntu.com/q/941273/672702. I hope thats the way. If it was, the option 3 is the path to the answer. I don't know yet. Thanks

Comment: I see it's harder than I thought. **Here are more info:**  https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/92856/184