# How can I configure visudo to run a script with root privileges for a non root user?

Tags: permissions, scripts, visudo

I need than a deployer (member of group deploy) can run some scripts with root priviegies. But I dont want that deployers can run anythig. I try this.

### With a root user I do:

```
~$ echo "touch /opt/expe/\$file_name.txt" > create_file.sh
~$ echo "chown \$USER /opt/expe/\$file_name.txt" >> create_file.sh
~$ cat create_file.sh
touch /opt/expe/$file_name.txt
chown $USER /opt/expe/$file_name.txt

~$ sudo mv create_file.sh /opt/expe/create_file.sh
~$ sudo chgrp deploy /opt/expe/create_file.sh
~$ sudo chmod g+x /opt/expe/create_file.sh
~$ sudo visudo 
%deploy ALL=(root) NOPASSWD:/opt/expe/create_file.sh
```

### With a deploy not-root user I do:

```
~$ groups
deploy
~$ /opt/expe/create_file.sh
touch: cannot touch '/opt/expe/my_text.txt': Permission denied
chown: cannot access '/opt/expe/my_text.txt': No such file or directory
```

Why the touch command did not executed as root?

How can I do a script that excute commands as root for a non root user?

#### Refs:

- https://askubuntu.com/a/941213/672702
- https://askubuntu.com/a/73872/672702

Comment: Your sudoers entry removes the need to type a password - you still need to prepend the command with `sudo`

Comment: But if I prepend sudo I get:  /opt/expe/create_file.sh \n 
[sudo] password for user_deploy: \n 
Sorry, user user_deploy is not allowed to execute '/usr/bin/touch /opt/expe/my_text.txt' as root on this_server.