# Mount Veracrypt volume without having adminstrative privileges

Tags: permissions, veracrypt

when I try to mount a volume in veracrypt with an non administrative user, veracrypt asks me for:
[image: Administrator privileges required].

So how can I mount veracrypt volumes with an user having no administrative privileges?

The solution from this question [How can user mount an encrypted file container in VeraCrypt?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/930724/how-can-user-mount-an-encrypted-file-container-in-veracrypt) seems to lead to privilege escalation (according to https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/178610/is-it-secure-to-mount-veracrypt-without-sudo-password-in-this-way). So is there a *clean* way to do this? How do other "non-privileged" users run veracrypt?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Create a script that mounts a specific device and add it to sudoers.
A file container has the problem that it may be replaced by a modified version if it is not read only.

More infos see: 
https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/Command%20Line%20Usage.html

Use the ID for partitions:
`/v ID:53B9.....1EDCA`